# Creating an array with "hidden" extra indices

Tags: arrays, julia

```
type ExtendedJumpArray{T,T2} <: AbstractArray{Float64,1}
  u::T
  jump_u::T2
end

Base.length(A::ExtendedJumpArray) = length(A.u)
Base.size(A::ExtendedJumpArray) = (length(A),)
function Base.getindex(A::ExtendedJumpArray,i::Int)
  i <= length(A.u) ? A.u[i] : A.jump_u[i-length(A.u)]
end
function Base.setindex!(A::ExtendedJumpArray,v,i::Int)
  i <= length(A.u) ? (A.u[i] = v) : (A.jump_u[i-length(A.u)] = v)
end
similar(A::ExtendedJumpArray) = deepcopy(A)
indices(A::ExtendedJumpArray) = Base.OneTo(length(A.u) + length(A.jump_u))
```

I thought I was the cool kid on the block, creating an array which could index past its length (I am doing it for a specific reason). But Julia apparently doesn't like this:

```
julia> ExtendedJumpArray([0.2],[-2.0])
Error showing value of type ExtendedJumpArray{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1}}:
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching inds2string(::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  inds2string(::Tuple{Vararg{AbstractUnitRange,N}}) at show.jl:1485
 in _summary(::ExtendedJumpArray{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1}}, ::Int64) at .\show.jl:1490
 in #showarray#330(::Bool, ::Function, ::IOContext{Base.Terminals.TTYTerminal}, ::ExtendedJumpArray{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1}}, ::Bool) at .\show.jl:1599
 in display(::Base.REPL.REPLDisplay{Base.REPL.LineEditREPL}, ::MIME{Symbol("text/plain")}, ::ExtendedJumpArray{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1}}) at .\REPL.jl:132
 in display(::Base.REPL.REPLDisplay{Base.REPL.LineEditREPL}, ::ExtendedJumpArray{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1}}) at .\REPL.jl:135
 in display(::ExtendedJumpArray{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1}}) at .\multimedia.jl:143
 in print_response(::Base.Terminals.TTYTerminal, ::Any, ::Void, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::Void) at .\REPL.jl:154
 in print_response(::Base.REPL.LineEditREPL, ::Any, ::Void, ::Bool, ::Bool) at .\REPL.jl:139
 in (::Base.REPL.##22#23{Bool,Base.REPL.##33#42{Base.REPL.LineEditREPL,Base.REPL.REPLHistoryProvider},Base.REPL.LineEditREPL,Base.LineEdit.Prompt})(::Base.LineEdit.MIState, ::Base.AbstractIOBuffer{Array{UInt8,1}}, ::Bool) at .\REPL.jl:652
 in run_interface(::Base.Terminals.TTYTerminal, ::Base.LineEdit.ModalInterface) at .\LineEdit.jl:1579
 in run_frontend(::Base.REPL.LineEditREPL, ::Base.REPL.REPLBackendRef) at .\REPL.jl:903
 in run_repl(::Base.REPL.LineEditREPL, ::Base.##932#933) at .\REPL.jl:188
 in _start() at .\client.jl:360
```

Is there an easy way to do this without breaking the `show` methods, and whatever else may be broken? Or is there a better way to do this in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indices needs to return a tuple, just like `size`.

```
julia> Base.similar(A::ExtendedJumpArray) = deepcopy(A)

julia> Base.indices(A::ExtendedJumpArray) = (Base.OneTo(length(A.u) + length(A.jump_u)),)

julia> ExtendedJumpArray([0.2],[-2.0])
2-element ExtendedJumpArray{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1}}:
  0.2
 -2.0

julia> length(ans)
1
```

Having `indices` and `size` disagree in the dimensionality of an array, though, is likely to end with confusion and strife.  Some functions use `size`, whereas others use `indices`.  See display vs. length above.